# How to 301 redirect feed url to home page using .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, joomla, rss

I want to make 301 permanent redirect form this link

http://www.example.com/media-center/gum-guru-blog.feed?type=rss

to http://www.example.com/. I wrote following lines inside my .httaccess file but its not working.

```
RewriteRule /media-center/gum-guru-blog.feed?type=rss / [L,R=301]
redirect 301 /media-center/gum-guru-blog.feed?type=rss http://www.example.com
```

Comment: You cant access querystring like that.

Comment: mention full url and check

Comment: google "How to manipulate querystrings in mod-rewrite"

Comment: I have mentioned full URL but still not working.

Comment: You have to use `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}`

Comment: Hi anubhava, can you please post some sample code?

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `redirect 301` if you have a Query String  `?type=rss` you must use a Rewrite Rule with a Rewrite Condition including this Query String:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^type=rss$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^\/media-center\/gum-guru-blog\.feed$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /? [R=301,L]
```

Use the [NC] Flag to be case-insensitive, if needed.